# Comparing effect sizes across multiple groups within meta analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size

I have multiple studies on a particular effect, each study tracks certain other criteria, and each has a control group. The units of measurement in each study are not always convertible between each other. For each study I calculated an effect size (bias corrected Hedge's g and its standard error). I'd like to do a comparison of effect size among the different criteria groups, and I'm just not sure where to start.

Here is how the data is organized (but with many more studies):

[image]

I can calculate confidence intervals for the effect size for each study and do a meta analysis for effect size for any combination of the factor criteria using R method `metagen`.

**Question:** Can I perform a statistical test to compare effect size between factor groups? For example, can I say that based on this meta analysis, the difference in effect sizes between group ACE and group BCF are statistically significant (or not)? Assume I have multiple studies for each combination of factor levels.

This is far outside of my statistical knowledge, so any help, advice, references are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like a meta-regression problem, but perhaps I misunderstand.

Comment: @mdewey Thanks for that info. I hadn't seen meta-regression before and am reading about it now. That might turn out to be the correct method to use and the best I can get, but I'm interested if I can do a significance test comparison on mean effect sizes computed by the meta-analysis. E.g effect size for group1 vs effect size for group2 where each group has a few studies each of which compute an individual effect size. I know I can do a t-test for comparing groups within a single study, but don't know if that method generalizes to the meta-analysis level.

Comment: If you have a moderator variable with two values for study group then its coefficient from the meta-regression is what you need (with its confidence interval, of course).